# Match phrase in a list

Tags: python

I am looking to match a phrase inside a list.

I'm using python to match a phrase inside a list. The phrases can be inside the list, or they can not be inside a list.

```
list1 = ['I would like to go to a party', 'I am sam', 'That is 
correct', 'I am currently living in Texas']

phrase1= 'I would like to go to a party'
phrase2= 'I am sam'
```

If phrase1 and phrase 2 are inside the list1, return correct or 100%. The purpose of it is to make sure that phrase 2 and phrase 2 are matched word for word.

Conversely, If the phrase is not inside a list or only one phrase is inside, for instance in list 2, then return false or 0%.

```
list2 = ['I am mike', 'I don\'t go to party', 'I am sam']

phrase1= 'I would like to go to a party'
phrase2= 'I am sam'
```

phrases can be changed so that it can be different than just those two phrases. For instance, it can be changed to whatever user sets like 'I am not good.'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you simply want to check for membership in the list:

```
list1 = ['I would like to go to a party', 'I am sam', 'That is correct', 'I am currently living in Texas']

phrase1 = 'I would like to go to a party'
phrase2 = 'I am sam'

if phrase1 in list1 and phrase2 in list1:
    # whatever you want, this will execute if True
    pass
else:
    # whatever you want, this will execute if False
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about I understand you but I guess maybe you can try

```
if phrase1 in list1
```

to check whether a phrase is in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a comprehension:

```
def check(phrase_list, *phrases):
  return all(p in phrase_list for p in phrases)
```

In use:

```
list1 = ['I would like to go to a party', 'I am sam', 'That is correct', 'I am currently living in Texas']

phrase1= 'I would like to go to a party'
phrase2= 'I am sam'

print(check(list1, phrase1, phrase2))
#True
print(check(list1, 'I am sam', 'dragon'))
#False
```

You can also use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Like this:

```
set(list1) >= {phrase1, phrase2}
#True
```

Or like this:

```
#you can call this the same way I called the other check
def check(phrase_list, *phrases):
  return set(list1) >= set(phrases)
```

**Edit**

To print 100% or 0% you could simply use an if statement or use boolean indexing:

```
print(('0%', '100%')[check(list1, phrases)])
```

To do this in your `return` statement:

```
return ('0%', '100%')[the_method_you_choose]
```

Comment: Instead of returning true, how to assign a value like 100%?

Comment: What you're looking for is called an `if` statement... I edited my answer..

Comment: I'd like to add up the % and return the complete % at the end. So, if I got both correctly(You have two print statements above), it'd be 100%. If not, 50%. What's best way to do this?

Comment: Try this: `len(set(list1) & set(phrases)) / len(phrases)`